# SQL Error---Literal not matching Format

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Guys I'am trying to retrieve date from another table in oracle from java and the trying to insert it in some other table but it keeps showing 
---->`java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`.

```
  rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from a_seq_mtx"); 
  while(rs.next()) { 
        //Checking range of ----range_base to range_base+2--- for each rows 
        date_start = rs.getString(1); 
        //Storing date for each row which is to be checked 
        date_end = rs.getString(2); 
        stmt1.executeQuery("insert into a_pattern values('"+date_start+"','"+date_end+"'
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: also, the DDL of the tables in question, and which data is transferred from where to where.

Comment: With no other info: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01861.php

Comment: rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from a_seq_mtx");
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        //Checking range of ----range_base to range_base+2--- for each rows
                        date_start = rs.getDate(1);   //Storing date for each row which is to be checked
                        date_end = rs.getDate(2);                                                                                             stmt1.executeQuery("insert into a_pattern values ('"+date_start+"','"+date_end+"')");

Comment: Post your code in the question, not the comments.

Comment: You should parameterize your insert and avoid literals.

Comment: Using literal instead of a date for a date field is wrong. See my answer.

Comment: Why are you doing separate select and insert steps, instead of `insert .. select` in one step?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to insert a **string literal** into a **DATE** column, you are most likely to get an **error** related to mismatch of **date format**.

The only instance when you might be just lucky is, that your **NLS_DATE_FORMAT** matches the date literal format, and Oracle is forced to do an **internal data type conversion**.

You must always explicitly convert the string literal into date using **TO_DATE** and proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

For example,

`'24-FEB-2015'` is a string enclosed within single quotes. It is not a date. However, `to_date('24-FEB-2015','DD-MON-YYY')` is a date.